# Wrong output on date

Tags: php

```
       if(isset($_POST['submit_event'])){
               $m = $_POST['event_month']; 
               $y = $_POST['event_year'];
               $d = $_POST['event_day'];


              $date = date('Y-n-d',strtotime($y. '-' .$m. '-' .$d));
              echo $date;
                          //i always get 2013-10-07
        }
```

All my inputted datas are correct although the output is always wrong and the same.

Comment: sample input: Year = 2013 Month = 10 Day = 28. But i always get 2013-10-07

Comment: [It works just fine](http://ideone.com/CHm9Gv). `$_POST['event_day']` is probably wrong.

Comment: i printed my variable for day but it's correct :/

Comment: Print `$y. '-' .$m. '-' .$d` and `strtotime($y. '-' .$m. '-' .$d)` as well.

Comment: i printed $y. '-' .$m. '-' .$d and the output is correct as for strtotime($y. '-' .$m. '-' .$d) the output is wrong :/

Comment: Well there are quite a few *Notes* in [the manual for `strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). You might want to review them, to see if they will help. e.g. it says to prefer [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: Provide a code that we could run and see the issue

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_event']) && isset($_POST['event_month']) && isset($_POST['event_year']) && isset($_POST['event_day'])) {
  $m = $_POST['event_month']; 
  $y = $_POST['event_year'];
  $d = $_POST['event_day'];
  $date_pre = $y. '-' .$m. '-' .$d;
  $time = strtotime($date_pre)
  $date = date('Y-n-d', $time);
  echo $date;
}
// For debugging:
else {
   echo "Not all variables have been set."
}
```